# How to dynamically display links while clicking on other link

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone help me in resolving this.

you can find my code here http://jsfiddle.net/Akz8j/17/

While clicking USEP 1, 1.2, 1.2, 1.3 and 2 should come i.e; Loan & Subsidy and TMO (Main heading)

while clicking UWSP the details below that should appear i.e; Loan & Subsidy and RF

While going to that url, only USEP and UWSP should appear.

Can anyone help me in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not able to do that in html, must use script

Comment: @MR.T.K. Thanks for your suggestion. I have added JavaScript tag also

Comment: check this link using jquery
http://jsfiddle.net/Akz8j/23/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery hide() and show() method to hide / show any html content...

check

```
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_effects.asp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar with no scripting

http://jsfiddle.net/jzaun/Akz8j/24/

but you need a supported browser (chrome.)